# getting a package on CRAN to pass winbuilder tests (to get it on CRAN) with a linux specific package (doMC)

Tags: r, devtools, cran, domc

So, I'm ready to get my package on CRAN, but I have used the doMC package, which is only available on linux on CRAN (it is available on R-forge for windows). I don't get any errors on devtools:check(), but I do get the following error back when CRAN tries to build it with winbuilder. I imagine there are packages that use that package and the doMC package itself is linux specific.

Here is the error:
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package required but not available: 'doMC'

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR, 1 NOTE

Comment: Why do you use `doMC` and not `doParallel` or `doFuture`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ralf Stubner's answer works best. I changed everything to doParallel and it works fine. "Why do you use doMC and not doParallel or doFuture?"

Answer (score 1):

I'd just add something like:

`doMC` - Package not available for Windows

Then if you want to get a little more rigorous add this to where you use actually use a function for `doMC`:

```
if (!requireNamespace("doMC")) {
  stop("package doMC required to do this thing....")
}
```

Comment: Where precisely would you put this? Can you give a reproducible function?

Comment: Right before you use whichever function you are using from doMC. That way for users it fails with an informative message.

Comment: Will this work on @import roxygen2 documentation statements? That's where I think things are failing, I believe.

Comment: I think `R CMD check` is failing because you are building it on Windows and `doMC` isn't available on windows. What makes you think it is a roxygen thing? In your Imports in your DESCRIPTION file you likely have doMC... Is the repo public?